# figure legend only printing first letter

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I try to print a figlegend with only one line, but I only get the first letter. I have the following script for making the plot:

```
from pylab import *
k = plot((0, 1),(1, 1))
figlegend((k),('Limit'),loc='lower center')
savefig('test.pdf')
```

The output is: [image: output]

What am I doing wrong? (Or is it a bug?)

Comment: `('Limit')` is not interperted as a tuple in python, `('Limit',)` is. My guess is that `['Limit']` should work just fine.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I haven't figured out whether it is a bug or intentional (for some reason) in matplotlib, but in order to get a full legend label you need to leave a trailing comma on your list of labels:

```
figlegend((k),('Limit',),loc='lower center')
```

change that line and your code:

```
from pylab import *
k = plot((0, 1),(1, 1))
figlegend((k),('Limit',),loc='lower center')
savefig('test.pdf')
```

produces the figure:

[image: full legend label]

Alternatively, one can use `[]` to achieve the same result:

```
figlegend((k),(['Limit']),loc='lower center')
```

Comment: It's a feature of Python: to specify a single-element list, you need that syntax to differentiate it from just some scalar value in parens. http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences

Comment: This is the weirdest quirk of Python I've come across yet. So grateful you found this out.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your problem is the following.

For the names of the legend, you have to surround it in square brackets, like this:

```
figlegend((k),[('Limit')],loc='lower center')
```

as you can see the legend name 'limit' is surrounded in square brackets, and this will then display the full name.

```
Here would be the full code:
from pylab import *
k = plot((0, 1),(1, 1))
figlegend((k),[('Limit')],loc='lower center')
savefig('test.pdf')
```